# Injecting template in ui-view is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ui-router module for my app.

My index.js file is -

```
angular.module("gameApp", ["ui.router"])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/game");

        $stateProvider
       .state("test-your-quickness", {
           url: "/test-your-quickness",
           templateUrl: "../../index.html",
           abstract: true
       })
       .state("test-your-quickness.game", {
           url: "/game",
           template: "<h1>hello</h1>"
        });
    });
```

index.html file -

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <title>Test Your Quickness</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
 </head>
 <body ng-app="gameApp">
   alert("hello");
   <div ui-view=""></div>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="commons/js/index.js"></script>
```

But when I go to 'game' state, the template is not being injected in the index.html.
Please correct me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is a little off. Don't define your index.html as template for the outer most state.

When you open index.html, the ng-app directive will bootstrap your application - the index.html is automatically rendered to the browser. Now when you define states which have a template(Url) this will only *then* get rendered into the appropriate `ui-view` tag.

The correct code would be like this:

```
angular.module("gameApp", ["ui.router"])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/game");

    $stateProvider
      .state("game", {
          url: "/game",
          template: "<h1>hello</h1>"
       });
});
```